# TypeAhead autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am new to typeahead autocomplete, I read the docs and started to work, but, autocomplete is not working

what i did is

```
$('#homeSearchBox').typeahead({
    order: "desc",
    source: {
        data: window.hotelNameArr
    },
    // source:  hotelNameArr,
    callback: {
        onInit: function (node) {
            console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);
        }
    }
});
```

hotelNameArr array is

```
["xxxxxxxxx, xxxxx", "yyyyyyy,yyyyyyyyyy", "zzzzzzzz - zzzzz - zzz, mmmmm", "cccccccc,rrrrrrrrrr", "cccccccc, ccccccccc"]
```

Is there anything i am missing ?, Thanks in advance

Comment: did u define hotelNameArr in your code anywhere

Comment: @Krishna which plugin are you using !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik : typeahead.js 0.10.5